# Cross-lagged-Panel SEM: negative covariance between latent variables. Ignore Warning in lavaan?

Tags: covariance, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have some issues with the interpretation of the output of my cross-lagged-model. First things first. Here is the model:

```
'
 us_t1a =~ opin_t1 + exp_t1 + know_t1 + free_t1 + curi_t1 
 us_t2a =~ opin_t2 + exp_t2 + know_t2 + free_t2 + curi_t2
 us_t3a =~ opin_t3 + exp_t3 + know_t3 + free_t3 + curi_t3
 us_t4a =~ opin_t4 + exp_t4 + know_t4 + free_t4 + curi_t4
 us_t5a =~ opin_t5 + exp_t5 + know_t5 + free_t5 + curi_t5
 us_t6a =~ opin_t6 + exp_t6 + know_t6 + free_t6 + curi_t6
 
 dep_t1b =~ stress_t1 + hap_t1_re + enjoy_t1_re + sad_t1 + down_t1
 dep_t2b =~ stress_t2 + hap_t2_re + enjoy_t2_re + sad_t2 + down_t2
 dep_t3b =~ stress_t3 + hap_t3_re + enjoy_t3_re + sad_t3 + down_t3
 dep_t4b =~ stress_t4 + hap_t4_re + enjoy_t4_re + sad_t4 + down_t4
 dep_t5b =~ stress_t5 + hap_t5_re + enjoy_t5_re + sad_t5 + down_t5
 dep_t6b =~ stress_t6 + hap_t6_re + enjoy_t6_re + sad_t6 + down_t6
 
 #covariances of disturbances of the latent variables
 us_t1a ~~ dep_t1b
 us_t2a ~~ dep_t2b
 us_t3a ~~ dep_t3b
 us_t4a ~~ dep_t4b
 us_t5a ~~ dep_t5b
 us_t6a ~~ dep_t6b
 
  #correlations
 hap_t1_re ~~ enjoy_t1_re
 hap_t2_re ~~ enjoy_t2_re
 hap_t3_re ~~ enjoy_t3_re
 hap_t4_re ~~ enjoy_t4_re
 hap_t5_re ~~ enjoy_t5_re
 hap_t6_re ~~ enjoy_t6_re
 
 exp_t1 ~~ know_t1
 exp_t2 ~~ know_t2
 exp_t3 ~~ know_t3
 exp_t4 ~~ know_t4
 exp_t5 ~~ know_t5
 exp_t6 ~~ know_t6
 
 #regression and autoregression of latent variables
 dep_t1b ~ us_t1a 
 dep_t2b ~ us_t1a + us_t2a + dep_t1b 
 dep_t3b ~ us_t2a + us_t3a + dep_t2b 
 dep_t4b ~ us_t3a + us_t4a + dep_t3b 
 dep_t5b ~ us_t4a + us_t5a + dep_t4b 
 dep_t6b ~ us_t5a + us_t6a + dep_t5b 

 us_t2a ~ us_t1a 
 us_t3a ~ us_t2a 
 us_t4a ~ us_t2a 
 us_t5a ~ us_t4a 
 us_t6a ~ us_t5a'
```

If I run the model (using FIML for missings and MLR for robust estimations) R prompts the following Warning:

```
The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
    does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
    (= -1.147136e-04) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that
    the model is not identified.
```

So I used my whole weekend for troubleshooting. And I'm pretty sure I found the reason for the warning. The covariances between the latent variables (eg. the disturbances of the latent variables) and the regressions are insignificant and mainly negative.

```
Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  dep_t1b ~                                                             
    us_t1a            0.028    0.962    0.029    0.977    0.026    0.026
  dep_t2b ~                                                             
    us_t1a           -0.038    0.054   -0.712    0.476   -0.036   -0.036
    us_t2a            0.027    0.052    0.527    0.598    0.027    0.027
    dep_t1b           0.736    0.035   21.016    0.000    0.719    0.719
  dep_t3b ~                                                             
    us_t2a           -0.057    1.021   -0.056    0.955   -0.057   -0.057
    us_t3a            0.030    1.238    0.024    0.981    0.029    0.029
    dep_t2b           0.749    0.035   21.307    0.000    0.765    0.765
  dep_t4b ~                                                             
    us_t3a           -0.047    0.061   -0.781    0.435   -0.043   -0.043
    us_t4a            0.002    0.066    0.029    0.977    0.002    0.002
    dep_t3b           0.871    0.035   24.706    0.000    0.812    0.812
  dep_t5b ~                                                             
    us_t4a           -0.056    1.554   -0.036    0.972   -0.051   -0.051
    us_t5a            0.036    1.843    0.019    0.985    0.032    0.032
    dep_t4b           0.846    0.034   24.914    0.000    0.811    0.811
  dep_t6b ~                                                             
    us_t5a           -0.051    0.085   -0.604    0.546   -0.046   -0.046
    us_t6a            0.040    0.093    0.435    0.664    0.038    0.038
    dep_t5b           0.759    0.032   23.630    0.000    0.765    0.765
  us_t2a ~                                                              
    us_t1a            0.858    0.035   24.464    0.000    0.818    0.818
  us_t3a ~                                                              
    us_t2a            0.825    0.035   23.440    0.000    0.843    0.843
  us_t4a ~                                                              
    us_t2a            0.891    0.035   25.120    0.000    0.863    0.863
  us_t5a ~                                                              
    us_t4a            0.844    0.033   25.407    0.000    0.867    0.867
  us_t6a ~                                                              
    us_t5a            0.850    0.034   25.044    0.000    0.816    0.816

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  us_t1a ~~                                                             
   .dep_t1b          -0.044    0.324   -0.135    0.893   -0.123   -0.123
 .us_t2a ~~                                                             
   .dep_t2b          -0.017    0.003   -5.166    0.000   -0.115   -0.115
 .us_t3a ~~                                                             
   .dep_t3b          -0.005    0.127   -0.039    0.969   -0.040   -0.040
 .us_t4a ~~                                                             
   .dep_t4b          -0.010    0.008   -1.248    0.212   -0.085   -0.085
 .us_t5a ~~                                                             
   .dep_t5b          -0.016    0.171   -0.093    0.926   -0.132   -0.132
 .us_t6a ~~                                                             
   .dep_t6b          -0.018    0.012   -1.572    0.116   -0.113   -0.113
```

Since the fit-measures and the factorloadings are okay (all over 0.5 std. and no heywood cases) I would ignore the Warning and come to the conclusion that there is no significant correlation between those two phenomena (us and dep).
Datasize is 2773 observations which is a good amount I guess.

Here some additional information:

If I delete the regressions between the "us" and "dep" the covariances stay negative and insignificant but the warning disappears. Same thing if I add a "phantom variable" for controlling fixed effects.

So the main questions is: would you agree with my interpretation?
Or do you have another hint for me?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are confusing the estimated covariance parameters with the asymptotic *sampling* covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (`vcov(fit)`), the diagonal of which are the squared *SE*s of the parameters you estimate.  The warning says that if you replicate your study many times, storing each estimated parameter in a column and each replication/sample in a row, you should expect (multi)collinearity among some parameter estimates.  That is, there might be some redundancy.  Potentially due to regressing `dep` variables on concurrent `us` variables as well as the Lag-1 `us` variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
It helped a lot. Not that I understand entirely but it gave me a decent push in the right direction I think. You made a good guess about the source of the warning it seems. If I exclude the regression between dep_t1b and us_t1a the warning vanishes. But shouldn't it also work the other way around?  Because if I delete the path between dep_t2b and us_t1a instead, I got the same warning.

Comment: I expected the concurrent paths to cause a problem because they might introduce a feedback loop (making your model recursive), although I can't see that clearly.  I might be way off, and the disappearing warning is a coincidence.  But I wouldn't expect deleting Lag-1 paths to resolve the problem, because those are not what would make the model recursive.  Identification is very difficult to determine in large/complex models.  Sorry I can't be more help there.

Comment: No worries you helped me a lot. Thanks again! As soon as I have an answer I'll post it here. I think it might be of interest for others with similar troubles.